# Why PriorityQueue requires API 24 in Android

Tags: android, priority-queue

`PriorityQueue` was added in Java 1.5

`new PriorityQueue()`is enabled in Android, but

```
  new PriorityQueue(new Comparator() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            return 0;
        }
    });
```

requires API 24. Why?

Answer (score 8):

Because [`PriorityQueue(Comparator)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue(java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20E%3E)) constructor was added to the SDK in API level 24. In JDK, that constructor was added in Java 8.

For compatibility with earlier API levels, you can use [`PriorityQueue(int,Comparator)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue(int,%20java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20E%3E)) that has been there since API level 1.

Comment: Java != android, that's why it wasn't added until API 24

Comment: Thx, I thought Android SDK contains JDK. So JDK was modified in Android?

Comment: There's no `PriorityQueue(Comparator)` constructor in JDK until JDK 8.

Answer (score 1):

That is because [PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) in Java 1.5 does not have  `PriorityQueue (Comparator<? super E> comparator)` constructor at all. It was implemented only in [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue(java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20E%3E)), and only in API 24.

You can use Java's `PriorityQueue (int initialCapacity, Comparator<? super E> comparator)` [constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue(int,%20java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20E%3E)) from Android API 1

Answer (score 1):

`PriorityQueue(Comparator)` constructor was implemented in `API level 24`.
 **Android Developers reference:**
[image]